# regex that matches an optional second group

Tags: regex

Given the following:

```
1. foo
2. foo:asc
3. foo:desc
4. foo:
5. foo:burp
```

I would like to match a sequence of characters, and an optional second sequence only if prefixed by : and is asc or desc

I should match:

```
1. group 0 = foo, group 1 = <empty>
2. group 0 = foo, gorup 1 = asc
3. group 0 = foo, gorup 1 = desc
4. should fail
5. should fail
```

I've tried with:

```
  [^:]+:?(\basc\b|\bdesc\b)?
```

But it doesn't work as expected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
^[^:]+(?::\b(asc|desc)\b)?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NMUAB1/1)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `[^:]+` - 1 or more chars other than `:`
- `(?::\b(asc|desc)\b)?` - an optional occurrence of

  - `:` - a colon
  - `\b(asc|desc)\b` - an `asc` or `desc` as whole word
- `$` - end of string.